# Using Azure Function V3, how do I inject existing Ilogger into new class file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-functions, ilogger

I have created a new Azure Function, V3, CORE 3.1, using VS2019. It uses a basic HTTPTrigger. I have created a new class file and would like to inject the existing Ilogger into it. How can this be achieved? I'm new to this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "existing ILogger" - would you like to inject your specific `ILogger` implementation/configuration within your Azure Function or are you interested in passing `ILogger` instance (e.g. from the trigger method) to the new class instance?

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek If possible i would like to use the one from the trigger method in the new class instance, would save having to generate a new one.

Comment: Then just pass that `ILogger` instance when invoking the constructor of your new class.

Comment: I have my Azure Function configured with Dependency Injection. If you want to go that route I can show you an example. Otherwise just pass it in manually like @ZdeněkJelínek suggested.

Comment: So like this NewClass.NewClassMethod(log)? I have tried this and it works, just wasn't sure if this was the best way going about it, or if it was better to DI it into the new file.

Comment: @knowonecanknow If you get some time to post your example that would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have a Function which writes logs to App Insights and I use ILogger.

You can use ILogger like this with Dependency Injection in your other service/helper classes.

```
public interface IExampleClass
{
    void ExampleMethod();
}

public class ExampleClass : IExampleClass
{
    private readonly ILogger<ExampleClass> _logger;

    public ExampleClass(ILogger<ExampleClass> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void ExampleMethod()
    {
       _logger.LogInformation("Example info log");
    }
}
```

I enable logging in the Startup file and register DI.

```
class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddLogging();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<ExampleClass, IExampleClass>();
    }
}
```

Which can be invoked by the main class.

```
public class ThisIsAnAzureFunction
{
    private readonly IExampleClass _exampleClass;

    public ThisIsAnAzureFunction(IExampleClass exampleClass)
    {
        _exampleClass = exampleClass;
    }

    [FunctionName("SomeAzureFunctionName")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            //Try some stuff
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //Log some stuff
            log.LogError(exception);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, what do you have for interface IExampleClass?

Comment: Currently nothing but you can just make your interface have any public members you want to expose. If you don't plan on unit testing or want to use the interface you can skip it.

Comment: Reason i ask is that i get an error (CS0246) on IExampleClass (type or namespace is missing).

Comment: I've added an example interface to the answer

Comment: Thanks, that removes the error. I have tried calling this using _exampleClass.ExampleMethod(); however nothing is output. Not receiving any errors, it runs and completes as expected, just no log. I did have to make the following changes to get it to compile.

1. AddTransient<IExampleClass, ExampleClass> Had to swap around interface and class.
2. Changed _logger.Info to _logger.LogInformation

Comment: Where are you logging too? I've only logged to App Insights with my Function. Do you have your telemetry key added to the Functions Application Settings?

Comment: Currently i'm doing local debugging so would expect the log to output to the console like the existing logger does.

Comment: Ok, so figured this out, seems i was really overcomplicating the matter. Have add in the code i have used to allow this to work. Thanks for all your help, really appreciate it, hope the edit is insightful!